# get avatar omniauth discord Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, omniauth

in my user.rb i try save a link to avatar:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
user.provider = auth.provider
user.uid = auth.uid
user.email = auth.info.email
user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
user.image = auth.info.image
end
```

it works with omniauth-google-oauth2 but with discord I get only half of image src. for example:

```
https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/714396517990037405/
```

where /714396517990037405/ is user id, image name is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug on part of the `omniauth-discord` gem. They [concatenate the URL without checking whether an avatar is actually set](https://github.com/adaoraul/omniauth-discord/blob/b8d9789170c988250401c4c81b97cb90a0c0d1e1/lib/omniauth/strategies/discord.rb#L23).

But if you look at the [Discord documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object), `avatar` is actually of type `?string` so it can be `null`.

General advice: if something isn't working and it's open source, take a look behind the scenes. Chances are you'll not only quickly find an explanation or solution but you'll also learn something about the things you're working with in the process.